# Voltage Follower Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: Op-Amp Diagram]
I am trying to increase the current available from my [Adafruit DAC](https://www.adafruit.com/product/935) going to a flow controller that needs a control voltage between 0-5V at 4-40 mA, using the included op-amp, a [TLV2462CP](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/tlv2462.pdf) circuit.

The problem is when I drive a voltage into the IN+ the output voltage doesn't change.
Did I wire this wrong?

Additional Information:
I am using a rail to rail because I need to be able to get to lower voltages such as 0.25V and a high of at least 4.95V to step through all the points for my flow controller. I am reading in voltages using a ADS1115 ADC and a program to record all the data.
Photos of my setup:
[Photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p6ih.jpg)
[Photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybMW8.jpg)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybMW8.jpg)
[Photo3][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmI46.jpg)][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmI46.jpg)

Comment: What output voltage do you measure? (Please try answering comments by updating your question using the edit link)

Comment: Your circuit seems OK. But what do you mean with `when I drive a voltage into the IN+ the output voltage doesn't change`? Does it stay at 0V or something? What is connected to the output?

Comment: It should work, except I don't see the purpose why the 2k2 resistor is there. A voltage follower could just connect output to inverting input directly.

Comment: @Justme `I don't see the purpose why the 2k2 resistor is there` Please see: [this](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/precisionhub/archive/2014/07/15/resistors-in-the-feedback-of-a-buffer-ask-why), [this](http://web.mit.edu/6.301/www/OP27c.pdf) (p.12) and [this](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD797.pdf) (p.13).

Comment: @RohatKılıç Yes I know in general why it would be there, but my point was why did the OP thought is is necessary and put it in there in the first place. Hardly a $5 Adafruit DAC would need a $10 wideband op-amp such as the good old AD797 (which seemed to be the favourite audio op-amp for audio electronics course lecturers at the uni..)

Comment: I was on the understanding you always have a resister between your -input and the output for a voltage follower. Even if I remove the resistor and just connect the -in to the output I get the same 1v out.

Comment: Well, clearly it was not a loose connection in the resistor then. Is the connection between DAC output and opamp +in OK? What voltages do you see there? Does the op-amp have reliable 5V and ground supply connections as well? Is the DAC ground connected to opamp ground?

Comment: There is a solid 5.1V power supply on the supply connections going into the Op-amp and I having the DAC output between 0.5V al the way to 4.9V. all the connection seem solid and I have tested them multiple times.

Comment: What did you with the shutdown pin? And what do you do with unused pins. Other simple questions did you follow the power supply recommendations of the datasheet? If all this does not help, please post a picture of your setup

Comment: @Navaro I am using the Raspberry Pi as a power supply as well as a low noise instrument power supply I have from other projects. As for the unused pins I am have them floating.

Comment: I meant did you decouple the op-amp with atleast one capacitor. I would recommend making voltage divider to half Vcc and configuring the unused op-amp as voltage follower. If the unused op-amp is saturing because you left it floating it might cause the issue you are observing.

Comment: @Navaro Would it be advisable to just set the unused on to gnd?

Comment: No, because of offset the inputs will never be the same. So if place vcc/2 on the non inverting input in a unity-buffer configuration.

Comment: @Navaro I added a voltage divider to the unused set as a voltage follwer and I am still getting only 1 v out on the used ones regardless of what input I am setting from my DAC.

Comment: Okay I hate to say this everyone but I went to the second output instead of the first and it is working fine now. I guess I just got a bad chip. Thank you all for the help I really appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had a chip with a bad input on the first set of terminals, but all the advice and answers here lead me to checking the inputs and really helped so if you are having a similar problem use some of the troubleshooting made in the comments.[image]